# Studio Controls won't launch in Ubuntu Studio

Tags: sound, ubuntu-studio

I haven't run Studio Controls for a while since I haven't been recording and Pulse works fine for basic operations. But I'd like it if Studio Controls would open when I do decide to record. When I try and launch through terminal, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/studio-controls", line 1837, in <module>
    us = StudioControls()
  File "/usr/bin/studio-controls", line 605, in __init__
    self.refresh_pulse_tab(self.pj_bridge)
  File "/usr/bin/studio-controls", line 1315, in refresh_pulse_tab
    self.pj_direct.set_text('none')
AttributeError: 'StudioControls' object has no attribute 'pj_direct'
```

Is this something I can/should fix, or do I just wait until the next release?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem after a crash from Ardour. I don't know if the two events (the Ardour crash and the following Studio Controls malfunction) are related, the point is that from the terminal I noticed that Studio Controls was crashing after reading the configuration file in `~/.config/autojack/autojack.json`:

```
$ studio-controls 

install path: /usr
Config file: ~/.config/autojack/autojack.json

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/studio-controls", line 1837, in <module>
    us = StudioControls()
  File "/usr/bin/studio-controls", line 605, in __init__
    self.refresh_pulse_tab(self.pj_bridge)
  File "/usr/bin/studio-controls", line 1315, in refresh_pulse_tab
    self.pj_direct.set_text('none')
```

I fixed it by deleting the configuration file:

```
rm ~/.config/autojack/autojack.json
```

Deleting the file restores the Studio Controls configuration to default.

Comment: I ended up enabling backports, which worked, but I'll try what you suggested.